# Powershell check if input is integer and > 0

Tags: arrays, loops, powershell, integer

How do I check if the user input is an integer and greater than zero and maximum 10?

I need to make a script which asks for a number from 0 to 10. This will be the amount of times the user can enter a number.

So if he enters 3, he has to be asked 3 times which number he wants to enter. When he entered the last number, the average has to been shown of the given number, and then the script ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
while ( (1..10) -notcontains $g)
{
    $g = read-host "How many numbers do you want to put in? (value from 1 to 10) " 
}    
$ar=@()
for ($i=0; $i -lt $g; $i++)
{
   $ar += read-host "Enter value $($i+1)"
}    
$averageArray = ($ar | Measure-Object -Average).average    
write-host "Average is : $averageArray"
```